# Sepolia ETH (SEP) not showing in Metamask

Tags: testnets, sepolia

The official Sepolia faucet website seems to be having issues (an invalid https certificate I think). I managed to find another faucet and was sent some SEP. The transaction hash is shown below. I can not however see it in Metamask when I connect to Sepolia.

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x63f8d50991ce53987ceb1eb2335eeb66cff2a75e99713b2807c3e88047a9bff8

Is this because I was sent POW SEP and not POS SEP which is what MM shows by default as SEP?

Comment: 10 days later and I am hitting the same certificate error

Comment: I found a faucet and got SEP (ETH?) in my wallet. I confirmed this via Etherscan's Sepolia explorer. When I try to make a transaction using Metamask, it says I have 0 SEP. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: if you are using Alchemy, I made it work using their RPC URL:

Network Name - Sepolia Testnet
New RPC URL - https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/[YOUR-API-KEY]
Chain ID - 11155111
Currency Symbol - SepoliaETH
Block explorer URL - https://sepolia.etherscan.io/

Answer (score 0):

I seem to see POS Sepolia network on Metamask
[image]

Repo:

1. Click network at the very top of metamask
2. Click "Add network"
3. Search for Sepolia and select

Also I work for Alchemy, we released a Sepolia faucet that gives up to 1 sETH if the sepolia faucet you were using doesn't work anymore: https://www.alchemy.com/faucets or sepoliafaucet.com